# Adding custom dialog box in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, css

I want to add a custom dialog box to get the text like "yes", "no", or "register", "cancel".
I don't want to use any framework. Currently I am using jQuery to achieve this. Please help to do it using CSS3 and HTML5 with Javascript!

My current code:

```
apprise('Do you wish to use the existing details?', {'verify':true}, function(r)  }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Android? Are you saying you no longer want to use jQuery (if so, what reason is there for that)? The code you've provided is incomplete/incorrect. What is the `apprise` function?

Comment: appraise is a jQuery way of doing. I am developing a hybrid app in android

Comment: You mean it's a [plugin](http://thrivingkings.com/apprise/) that you never mentioned in your question? I've no idea what a hybrid app is, but if you can use Javascript, and you have HTML, than there's no reason you can't use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
If(!confirm('Do you wish to use the existing details?')){
   return false;
}else{
    //If yes
    // Code here
}

//Or just continue here
```

In reply to you comment:

```
<div class='myMesssage' style='display:none'>
    <div class='content'>

    </div>
    <div class='buttons'>
        <input type='button' class='yesB' value='Yes'/> <input class='yesB' type='button' value='No'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function openMsg(msg){
    $(".myMessage .content").html(msg);
    $(".myMessage .buttons .yesB").click(function(){
            //Button function here, you could make this dynamic
           $(".myMessage").toggle();
     });

    $(".myMessage").toggle();
}
```

With this approach, you do need to change your logic somewhat, because now, the flow should continue from the button press in the message. But thats easy by dynamically assinging a function to the click event of the .yesB

Comment: this will provide me buttons with "OK" and "Cancel".

Comment: Yes I thought that what you were looking for.
Otherwise, just create a Div, and style it the way you like, with the buttons you like on it, and hide it until the message has to popup pops up, that way you have full control.

Comment: its not working for me. Its displaying nothing for me! ?I am not an expert in js. So might have missed something!

Comment: Did you call openMsg('Hello world'); or something like that? You do need to style the message div of course, this is not a ready to go package.